# Clickable area behind border?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have two divs : `<div class="top"></div>` and `<div class="bottom"></div>`, which fill up the top & bottom half of the page respectively.

I want to leave a 50px gap between those two divs so that the element behind them (`<div class="clickable"></div>`) is clickable inside that gap.

In the example below, I am sort of faking it so that you get an idea of the design I'm going for and the clickable area is obviously not clickable (due to the borders that exist right above it)

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this ? Check out my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bgtndevx/) to see what I'm talking about

The gradient that I'm using is a necessary background fro `top` and `bottom` as well as their 50% height with the 50px gap between them. I'm not looking for solutions of a specific height for `top` and `bottom`.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="clickable"></div>
    <div class="top">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
* {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;  
}
.clickable {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.top,.bottom {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.top div,.bottom div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.top {
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
.bottom {
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
}

.top div {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(147,189,69,1) 0%, rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(147,189,69,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(147,189,69,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(147,189,69,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(147,189,69,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(147,189,69,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#93bd45', endColorstr='#007db9e8',GradientType=0 );
}
.bottom div {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%, rgba(147,189,69,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(125,185,232,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(147,189,69,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(147,189,69,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(147,189,69,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(147,189,69,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(147,189,69,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#007db9e8', endColorstr='#93bd45',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `calc` and `margin` to create the gap (which is what it's for) ...and there is no need floats unless you want them.

`Calc` support is IE9 and up: [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

```css
* {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clickable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.top,
.bottom {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(50% - 25px);
}
.top {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.top div,
.bottom div {
  height: 100%;
}
.top div {
  background: lightblue;
}
.bottom div {
  background: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="clickable"></div>
  <div class="top">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```